# Случайное число из отрезка попадающее в интервал

Tags: java

Здравствуйте! Подскажите по коду, правильно он оформлен по задаче.

Задача.

> Создать программу, которая будет проверять попало ли случайно выбранное из отрезка [5;155] целое число в интервал (35;150) и сообщать результат на экран

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String args[]){
       final int a = 5;
        final int b = 155;
         int c = (int) (Math.random()*a + Math.random()*b);
       if(c >= 35 && c <= 150){
        System.out.println("Число " + c + " содержится в интервале (35,150)");
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("Число " + c + " не содержится в интервале (35,150)");
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ "Nofate"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вы считаете, что число в интервале [0;5]  плюс число в интервале [0;155] даст число из интервала [5;155] ?

Чтобы получить случайное число из интервала [a; b] воспользуйтесь формулой:

```
c = Math.random()*(b - a) + a
```

Проверяем:

```
[0; 1]*(b - a) + a = [0; b - a] + a = [a; b - a + a] = [a; b]
```